# Invoke a method of ng2-pdf-viewer from angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, pdf-viewer

I am new to angular 5. I am working on ng2-pdf-viewer. I need to invoke one of its method updateSize() in that plugin from my component. Can anyone tell me how can I access it from a component.

Here is the link of the plugin

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer

Comment: please add your code, did you try the sample https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-pdf-viewer

Comment: I tried the sample. I can access ng2-pdf-viewer as well.But I want to invoke a method which is available inside pdfmodule. How can I achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a template reference variable to access the public methods of ng2-pdf-viewer

Add a template variable named `#pdfViewer` in the html file like so

```
  <pdf-viewer
    #pdfViewer
    [src]="reportObject.src"
    [page]="reportObject.currentPage"
    [render-text]="true"
    >
  </pdf-viewer>
```

Use **ViewChild** decorator to reference it inside your component.

```
  import { PdfViewerComponent } from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';
  import {ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

  @ViewChild('pdfViewer') pdfComponent: PdfViewerComponent;
```

You can now access the methods of *ng2-pdf-viewer* using the pdfComponent variable like so

```
  this.pdfComponent.updateSize();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably achieve this by using `ViewChild`.

1. In you html template where you use pdf-viewer, write it as something like this `<pdf-viewer [src]="src"[original-size]="false" #pdfViewer></pdf-viewer>`.
2. Add `@ViewChild('pdfViewer') pdfViewer` into your component.

After that, you should be able to use the method like this `this.pdfViewer.updateSize()` and also methods inside the pdfViewer.